# Strange umlaut encoding on file system

Tags: php, encoding, diacritics

From time to time I encounter files that have a strange (wrong?) encoding of umlaut characters in their file names. Maybe the encoding comes from a Mac system, but I'm not sure. I work with Windows.

For example: 
`Volkszählung` instead of `Volkszählung` (try to use Backspace after the first ä).

When pasting it into an ANSI encoded file with notepad++ it inserts `Volksza¨hlung`.

I have two questions:
a) Where does that come from and which encoding is it?
b) Using `glob()` in PHP does not list these files when using the wildchard character `*`. How is it possible to detect them in PHP?

Comment: That's the difference between Unicode precomposed characters and combining characters. If Notepad++ treats the two parts like separate characters, then it must have poor Unicode support.

Comment: Your issue seems to be that an OS you're using is creating files with names that don't follow the right Unicode normalisation rules. Not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: @Andrea, that's not really the root problem; even if this particular string used the precomposed character, the application may encounter other strings that can't be normalized because no precomposed character exists.  It needs to be able to cope with combining characters.

Comment: @Wyzard I know that, but the problem I was referencing there is that their filesystem apparently has a mix of represnetations

Answer (score 3):

That's a [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character):  specifically, U+0308 COMBINING DIARESIS.  Combining characters are what let you put things like umlauts on *any* character, not just specific "precomposed" characters with built-in umlauts like U+00E4 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS.  Although it's not *necessary* to use a combining character in this case (since a suitable precomposed character exists), it's not *wrong* either.

(Note, this isn't an "encoding" at all:  in the context of Unicode, an encoding is a method for transforming Unicode [codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) numbers into byte sequences so they can be stored in a file.  UTF-8 and UTF-16 are encodings.  But combining characters are Unicode codepoints, just like normal characters; they're not something produced by the encoding process.)

If you're working with Unicode text, you should be using PHP's [mbstring](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) functions.  The built-in string functions aren't Unicode-aware, and see strings only as sequences of bytes rather than sequences of characters.  I'm not sure how mbstring treats combining characters, though; the documentation doesn't mention them at all, as far as I can see.

You should also take a look at the [grapheme functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.intl.grapheme.php), which are specifically meant to cope with combining characters.  A "grapheme unit" is the single visual character produced by a base character codepoint plus any combining characters that follow it.

Finally, the [PCRE regex functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) support a [`\X` escape sequence](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) that matches whole grapheme clusters rather than individual codepoints.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination! But I still can't access files containing combined characters in their file names. `scandir()` lists the files but `file_exists()` denies their existence. However, this works with "real" umlauts like U+00E4 (i.e. I use the correct encoding). As mentioned above, `glob()` does not even list these files.